# What does the "Function Call" activity mean in the Chrome profiler?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is this code that the browser is running that isn't code that I wrote?

[image: Fuction Call Activity on Chrome Profiler]

Answer (score 1):

[This Chrome Doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/performance-reference) says Function Call is "A top-level JavaScript function call was made (only appears when browser enters JavaScript engine)." But I'm still not sure exactly what that means.

Comment: It means the function was directly invoked by the browser, not by your other code. For example, a callback of setTimeout, requestAnimationFrame, DOM event.

Comment: So you're saying it might have been a line of code that I wrote ten (called by the browser)? Is there any way to tell what function it was, so that I can know how to optimize my program to run faster?

Comment: The function name should be revealed when you click the source file link at the end of the row.